# localhost doesn't work with UdpClient for NLog

Tags: localhost, nlog, udpclient

I can receive NLog messages with my `UdpClient` object through 127.0.0.1 but not localhost.

The targets from my NLog.config file are:

```xml
    <!-- this works -->
    <target name="<MyLogger" type="Chainsaw" address="udp://127.0.0.1:7777"/>

    <!-- this does not work, no messages received -->
    <!--<target name="MyLogger" type="Chainsaw" address="udp://localhost:7777"/>-->
```

I have tried various ways to open/configure my `UdpClient` object, including:

```cs
// this way
_udpClient = new UdpClient(settings.Port);

// this way
_endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, settings.Port);

/// this way
_udpClient = new UdpClient();
_endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), settings.Port);
_udpClient.Client.Bind(_endPoint);
```

I have tried all of the above and a number of variations.

I know I can use localhost in the config file since it works with another NLog client,  Log2Console.  I have lines for Log2Console in my config file that only differ by the target name (MyLogger <=> Log2Console).  Both 127.0.0.1 and localhost work with Log2Console.

I fear I am doing something dumb, but cannot see it.

Answer (score 0):

probably `localhost` will resolve the IP V6 address (`::1`), so the listener should also listen to that one.

You could use `udp4://localhost:7777` to force IP V4, see [the docs](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Chainsaw-target)